# content css returning "" with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So.. I am trying to get a code referenced at the content CSS of a page.

Here is my css:

```
.ja-e-assinante.slot ul.promocoes li a .saiba-mais:after {
    font-family: IconesNC;
    content: "\e623";
    float: right;
    font-size: 17px;
```

I'm using the following script code to get the value and i'm getting it, but it shows up as a Square() on my workspace and I need the "\e623" value.

```
String script = "return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.saiba-mais'),':after').content";

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
String content = (String) js.executeScript(script);
```

Comment: That means either you don't have the right font or the environment you're displaying it in doesn't support that particular character.

Comment: But can I get the content value as a 'text' or something instead of the code that references that char?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I need to compare the value that i'm getting with the script to that code "\623" and see if it's the same. On my browser the icon is showing up just fine.

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: You'll be able to get the character all right; it just won't show up as an icon because your console does not display text using your icon font.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Unicode Number with [String.charCodeAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt). Then you need to convert it to the Unicode-Entity.